# reload controller on back button angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How to reload the controller when the user click the back button???

I am using AngularJS v1.6.2 and angular-ui-router 0.4.2

The states:

```
   ...
   .state('cars.bmw', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/bmw',
        templateUrl: 'pages/cars/bmw.html?v=' + version
    })
    .state('cars.audi', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/audi',
        templateUrl: 'pages/cars/audi.html?v=' + version
    })
   ...
```

Check the location path and I'm injecting `{{}}` the header and the title:

```
...
if($location.path() === '/cars/bmw')
{
    $scope.pageHeader = "BMW Cars";
    $scope.curentMenu = "CARS";
    $scope.title = My Car Collection BMW";
}
...
```

the menu links:

```
...
<a ui-sref="cars.bmw" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">BMW</a>
...
```

The problem is for example if I am in `/cars/BMW` path and click the back button to `/cars/audi`, the title, header and `curentMenu` don't change, I have to manually refresh the page to reload the controller.

Comment: Think a better approach would be to resolve the state you attempt to infer using $location

Answer (score 0):

The code below will resolve your controller on each state change. Give it a shot.

```
.state('cars.bmw', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/bmw',
        templateUrl: 'pages/cars/bmw.html?v=' + version
        controller: 'YourController'
    })
```

Also, if you could post some HTML would help too.

Comment: Not working. I am not sure if its the best what i am doing checking the path. Each category has its own controller (ex: Cars, TV, Laptops): The controller for the cars is: `app.controller('cars', function($scope, $location) { if($location.path() === '/cars/bmw')
{
    $scope.pageHeader = "BMW Cars";
    $scope.curentMenu = "CARS";
    $scope.title = My Car Collection BMW";
}...}`
and so on for each path in the cars category.

Comment: it is not good what are you doing with those `if` statements. it is better if you use `state params` or even `resolve` for each state. can you please show how did you used my solution. once you add controller into state config it should be removed from html.

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the event for succesful page changes, $locationChangeSuccess.

When that event fires you could put whatever logic you run on pageload that you need to run when the controller initializes.

Code

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
    $scope.initFunction()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

`Scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
    $scope.initFunction()
});`

seems to work. I created a function in the app.js for each catogory and set the values for the title, curentMenu and pageheader:

```
var initHeader_Cars = function($scope, $location){
  if($location.path() === '/cars/bmw')
  {
      $scope.pageHeader = "BMW Cars";
      $scope.curentMenu = "CARS";
      $scope.title = "My Car Collection BMW";
  }
  if($location.path() === '/cars/audi')
  {
      $scope.pageHeader = "AUDI Cars";
      $scope.curentMenu = "CARS";
      $scope.title = "My Car Collection AUDI";
  }
};

var initHeader_Laptops = function($scope, $location){
  if($location.path() === '/laptops/acer')
  {
      $scope.pageHeader = "ACER";
      $scope.curentMenu = "Laptops";
      $scope.title = "Acer Models";
  }
};
```

and then i used in each category controller the locationChangeSuccess event:

```
app.controller('cars', function($scope, $location) {
  // init vaules
  initHeader_cars($scope, $location);
  $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
      // when click the back button
      initHeader_cars($scope,$location);
  });
});
```